# Can we remove the ethics tag?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, tags, burninate-request

I am uncertain of the place of "ethics" in the workplace, both the site and, you know, the actual workplace. I hasten to add, *this is because ethics are incredibly subjective*, and a cursory glance of ethical philosophy will show this. This is not because I'm all for looting the office supply cabinet<sup>1</sup>.

Having an "ethics" tag tacitly encourages questions with "ethics" related issues.

[This has been raised before](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/453/8146), where the consensus was that "ethics" related questions were better answered with a "logistical and strategic perspective".

Given that the  general consensus is that ethics isn't part of the scope of this site, can we remove the tags?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`

1: I prefer the term "aspecific repurposing for an unknown duration"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are Ethics part of our purview?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/453/are-ethics-part-of-our-purview)

Comment: @Jim this is... this is the same question i mention in my own question. I'm pretty sure it isn't a duplicate, I want to remove the tag.

Comment: Would something like [this](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6983/52929) work? It could have a bit of text pop up warning users about questions related to ethics?

Comment: @enderland yes, i like that a lot

Comment: @JimG. This is meta and the question you refer to is over 2 years old.  It is permissible to bring up this subject again.

Comment: @ReallyTiredOfThisGame for the sake of completeness, I believe it's _generally_ okay to dupe-close, even on meta, even after two (3, 4 etc) years. But in this _specific_ case, I am really with you, because ["preemptive de-duplication"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194489/165773) has been done fairly thoroughly

Answer (score 5):

I would vote for not removing ethics.

Although we can't answer a full-blown, should I do X or Y question, questions falling under the ethics tag often seem to lead to a general consensus from answerers. Most of the time, people are concerned about *fairness* in the workplace, or whether there is a consequence to their or a colleague's actions that they may not have considered. I think these are fair questions to be concerned about and usually reasonable.

As the answer people linked to said, answerers then tend to approach it from a logical point of view, but I think "ethics" is still a reasonable tag because it tends to mean "is this action appropriate for the workplace?", which I think *is* answerable on this site and not just opinion-based.

However, some ethical questions will not be in scope on this site, and will then be subject to the various close reasons (company specific or opinion based). I don't think this is a reason for deleting the tag though.

Edit: [enderland's suggestion of a pop-up to address these caveats](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3055/can-we-remove-the-ethics-tag#comment6896_3055) would, in my opinion, be a good idea.

Answer (score -5):

> Given that the general consensus is that ethics isn't part of the scope of this site...

[There's a past discussion where the consensus differed.](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/454/437)

> As long as the questions have enough detail to where they can be answered from a strategic view or focusing on consequences, then I don't personally see a problem with the question.

Comment: Um... is this the same question linked again? Is that a record for question links? Nobody should have a problem with the question linked - it is a fine question. But it has an "ethics" tag when it isn't about ethics (at all - look at what the OP there asks). It has an "ethics" tag and none of the answers answer in terms of ethics. So we have a tag that does nothing. Let's just remove it!